# Compute a conditional probability

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Let $x\colon[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous path with, and let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion on some probability space.

I want to compute the following conditional probability:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[f(B(t))\,\Big|\quad \sup_{s\in[0,t]}|B(s)-x(s)|<\varepsilon\right].
$$
Where $f$ is a given function.

Does this make sense?

I would like to know if it depends on the path of $x$, or only on $x(t)$? Is it just $f(x(t))$?

Comment: do you mean to say the inequality holds for *some* fixed $\epsilon >0$ or for *any* $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: @ gt6989b for fixed $\epsilon >0.$

Comment: I'm sure it depends on the path for generic $f$. For instance, let $t=1$ and consider $x(t)=\begin{cases} Nt & x \in [0,1-1/N] \\ 1-N^2(t-(1-1/N)) & x \in [1-1/N,1] \end{cases}$ where $N \gg 1$. Then $W(1)$, given your condition, will tend to be positive more than it is negative. On the other hand certainly this is not true if you take $x=0$, yet these end up at the same value at the end. Thus if $f$ is the identity, then in the first case the expectation should be positive and in the second case it should be zero.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I see what you mean.  But do you think it depends of the local behavior of x near 1? Say $x(t)=0$ on $[1−1/N,1]$ does it follow the expactation is $f(0)$?

Comment: I don't think so, because $W(t)$ is correlated with $W(s)$ for every nonzero $s,t$. The correlation weakens as you get further away, but it is still present.

Comment: Also, it could happen that $f$ is convex with minimum (resp. concave with maximum) at zero, in which case the expectation must be larger (resp. smaller) than $f(0)$ regardless of what $x$ is.

Comment: (Also I made a small error in the above; the point was for $x$ to be piecewise linear with two pieces, equal to 0 at 0, $N$ at $1-1/N$, and 0 at 1. But you know how to explicitly write down this function.)

Comment: Yes, I noticed the error, but I got the idea

Comment: concerning the above you are right even without the conditioning (which is basically the case $\epsilon=+\infty$) $\mathbb{E} f(W(t))\neq f(0)$.